# Redirect error laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect

Hello i am using createProduct page for my create form. And after i created a product i want to redirect to the same page with parameters. Can you help me with the following error please ?

web.php

```
Route::get('/admin/products/create','productsController@createProduct');
Route::post('/admin/products/creating','productsController@creatingProduct');
```

creating function

```
public function creatingProduct(){

    $product = new Product();
    $product->name = Input::get('name');
    $product->description = Input::get('description');
    $product->price = Input::get('price');
    $categories = Category::all();

    try {
       $product->save();
       $pageMessage =  prepareMessage("alert-success","Yahoooo!!","Eklendiii");
    } catch ( \Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
       $pageMessage =  prepareMessage("alert-danger","Üzgünüz!!","Ürününüz eklenemedi");
    }

     //  return view('admin.createProduct',compact('categories','pageMessage'));


     return Redirect::route('/admin/products/create')->with( 'pageMessage', $pageMessage );
}
```

create function

```
public function createProduct(){

    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('admin.createProduct',compact('categories'));

}
```

createProduct.bladde.php

```
    @if(isset($pageMessage))
    {!!$pageMessage!!}
    @endif  
    <form class="well form-horizontal" action="  {{url('admin/products/creating')}}" method="POST"  id="contact_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <!--{{ Form::open(['url' => '/admin/products/create', 'files' => true]) }}-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Ürün İsmi</label>  
  <div class="col-md-8 inputGroupContainer">
```

ERROR

```
InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314:
Route [/admin/products/create] not defined.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a URL into Redirect::route() which expects the name of a route instead.

```
return redirect('/admin/products/create')->with( 'pageMessage', $pageMessage );
```

If you're using an older version of Laravel I believe it would be

```
return Redirect::to('/admin/products/create')->with( 'pageMessage', $pageMessage );
```

You can set up a named route and use that also, it's quite simple:

```
Route::post( '/admin/products/creating', [
    'uses' => 'productsController@creatingProduct',
    'as'  => 'products.create'
]);
```

The benefits are that you can reference the route name throughout your application and if you decide to change the format of the URL you only have to do it in the one spot.

Comment: i have added my create function and view. Redirection works if i do it like the way you suggested but i cannot get pageMessage variable using {!!pageMessage!!}

Comment: Use {!! $pageMessage !!}, you're missing the dollar sign.

Comment: that was a typing mistake. It is with the dollar sign in the code. You can see above.

Comment: Using with() flashes data to the session, you'll have to retrieve it with session('pageMessage').

Answer (score 0):

You should use route name instead of url if you're using `route()`:

```
return redirect()->route('products.create');
```

So you can name your route:

```
Route::get('/admin/products/create', ['as' => 'products.create', 'uses' => 'productsController@createProduct']);
```

As alternative, you can use url like this:

```
return redirect('/admin/products/create');
```

Comment: That's a good answer, i will add a note: instead of naming your route the way you shows here, you can do it like so: `Route::get('/admin/products/create','productsController@createProduct')->name('products.create');`

Answer (score 0):

You defined `Redirect::route()` which is not define you inside your route file.

It should be like below:

```
return Redirect::to('/admin/products/create')->with( 'pageMessage', $pageMessage );
```